# JSON deserialize from another managed package

Tags: apex, json, serialize

In Salesforce if you try and do this:

```
JSON.serialize(data);
```

where `data` is an instance of a global Apex class in another managed package it will fail.

This seems like a completely arbitrary and pointless limitation, since all the global fields can be accessed anyway. So why did Salesforce do this, and is there any alternative?

Comment: What error message does it throw when it fails?

Answer (score 8):

There is a @JsonAccess annotation. Check this:

https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/summer20/release-notes/rn_apex_JsonAccessAnnotation.htm

This annotation has 2 parameters: serializable & deserializable with this 4 options:

- never: never allowed
- sameNamespace: allowed only for Apex code in the
  same namespace
- samePackage: allowed only for Apex code in the same
  package (impacts only second-generation packages)
- always: always
  allowed for any Apex code

Example:

@JsonAccess(serializable='never' deserializable='sameNamespace')

public class Foo {}

Comment: As links often break please post a summary of the linked content so that this answer will not become invalid if the link no longer works.

Comment: This is very welcome! Should have been in from the start!

Answer (score 3):

If the error message is:

> System.JSONException: Cannot serialize type from package: ...

then a Google leads you to Dan Watt's post [Salesforce: Serializing Objects from a Managed Package](http://www.danwatt.org/2015/01/salesforce-serializing-objects-from-a-managed-package/) that includes:

> Only custom objects, which are sObject types, of managed packages can
>   be serialized from code that is external to the managed package.
>   Objects that are instances of Apex classes defined in the managed
>   package can’t be serialized. (JSON Support)

Why? Who knows...

The only alternative that comes to mind is to duplicate the data structure using local Apex classes or build nested `Map<String, Object>` with matching names. Pretty horrible if the structure is complex.

Answer (score 2):

I also got this error.
Optionally you can ask from the package to expose it, with the annotation

```
@JsonAccess(serializable='always' deserializable='always')
```

Just will add that in case the class contains subclass, then both should be exposed with this annotation, otherwise you will get similar error on the inner class

```
@JsonAccess(serializable='always' deserializable='always')
public class DemoClass1{
    
    @JsonAccess(serializable='always' deserializable='always')
    public class MyInnerClass{
    
    }
}
```